# What drivers should I use?

Tags: drivers

I know i have Nvidia card, and i want to make sure I'm using the resources on my computer. Is this how my driver should be set up for maximum efficiency? Can someone explain what these options are?
[image]

Comment: All is OK. You've installed an Nvidia driver and CPU microcode.

Comment: What is the X.org X server? Will that use my nvidia card better than the binary?

Comment: That is an open source nouveau driver. It won't work better.